# Angular Getting selected let value

Tags: angular, html

I'm just learning Angular and I'm trying to get an id value from my search page.
My search page is working well, I can retrieve the items from my service and this is the code:

```
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card animated fadeIn fast" *ngFor="let cancion of canciones; let i = index">
        <img [src]="cancion.img" class="card-img-top" [alt]="cancion.cancion">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"> {{ cancion.artista }} </h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ cancion.idx }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{ cancion.cancion }}</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"> {{ cancion.lanzamiento }} </small></p>
            <p class="card-text">{{ cancion.lyrics }}</p>

            <button (click)="verCancion(i)" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block"> 
            Ver mas...
            </button>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is when I try to get cancion.idx for routing to a detail page, because i returns the array indexes (0,1,2...etc) and not the idx.

this is my component.ts

```
 verCancion( idx:number ){
console.log("id de disco en Busquedas => ", idx );
this._ruteador.navigate( ['/cancion', idx] );                // Redirigimos al componente cancion, especificandole el id de la cancion
}
```

And as I said, idx is not the value that I want.

Please, I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though code looks correct, try passing the current object in the ngFor,

```
 <button (click)="verCancion(cancion)"
```

and access the id in controller,

```
verCancion( cancion : any){
 console.log(cancion.idx);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sajeetharan, If I send the object I can get the id

Answer (score 0):

The solution is sending the object with its property, because if I send the loop value the function gets the array ordinal:

```
<button (click)="verCancion(cancion.idx)" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block"> 
        Ver mas...
        </button>
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation of why it addresses the problem.